# NodeJS: Making JavaPath-Plus work with a certain object search?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I can make normal searches perfectly fine (e.g. `jp.query(response.data.logs, '$..id');`)

but when I replace `id` with a steam3 id (which uses brackets and colons like this: `[U:1:123456789]`), it doesn't return any information even though there is stuff under that exact object.

Do I need to do something so that it can read the steam3?